# CUPS - Print Job is received but not printing

Tags: networking, printing, software-installation, canon, cups-lpd

I am trying to install a network printer just for home use. The printer works fine with my Windows 7 machine. But I thought why not put it on my Ubuntu Server as a network printer and so I did.

I installed cups already and it works without problems. Even the printer was recognized directly.

But when I try to print a document it always says: "Waiting for printer to become available." on the webpage. Any ideas on how I can fix this? Do I need to configure anything additionally for USB printers? By the way I am talking about a Canon MP260.

Comment: Wow what a gorgeous forum where you don't get any response within 3 days :DD

Answer (score 3):

Printer debugging information is here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems

---

If nothing of that helps, then try:

1. Disconnect the printer physically
2. Make sure the DEFAULT printer is something else e.g. `cups-pdf` (`PDF` in the GUI, `sudo apt-get cups-pdf` to install).
3. Remove / Delete the printer driver(s)/setup(s) you have in the GUI
4. Reboot (to make sure nothing related is still running)
5. Restore physical connection (this may install the driver automagically)
6. If 5) didn't happen, install manually
7. Test

For what it is worth:
I solved the same problem as in the question with the numbered steps above.
I had "unplugged or turned off" shown as I checked with `lpstat -d -p` in the Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=959710
Sorry I am also frustrated like you getting my LBP2900 to work, so I dont have much idea on this.

Comment: at least someone who is honest ;)